# Queries with MongoDB in Production (Authentication) not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am writing a very simple application with NodeJS and Mongoose.

If I disable authentication in Mongoose, everything works fine and I can access my records from the database. But when I turn on the authentication and configure my NodeJS code to use authenticated Mongoose connection it doesn't let me query my records and the web page keeps on loading.

Name of my database is "bears".

P.S. I have created my users in "Admin database and Bears" database. I have given a user of books database readwrite permissions and it works fine when I authenticate it through "Mongo" command or db.auth command. But it is not working through NodeJS/Mongoose.

Here is my code.

```
var mongoose     = require('mongoose');
var opt = {
user: 'bearsdev',
pass: 'bearsdev123!',
    auth: {
        authdb: 'bears'
    }
};

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/bearsdev',opt);
var Schema       = mongoose.Schema;

var BearSchema   = new Schema({
    name: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Bear', BearSchema);
```

In my server.js

```
var express    = require('express');        // call express
var app        = express();                 // define our app using express
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());  

var Bear     = require('../models/bear');

var bear = require('express').Router();

bear.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.json({ message: 'hooray! welcome to our api!' });   
});

bear.get('/bear',function(req, res) {
        Bear.find(function(err, bears) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);

            res.json(bears);
        });
});
app.use('/test', bear);
app.listen(8080);
```

localhost:8080/test works.
localhost:8080/test/bear keeps on loading.

I have tried different ways of authentication with Mongoose, e.g.

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://bearsdev:bearsdev123!@localhost:27017?authSource=bearsdev');
```

and

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://bearsdev:bearsdev123!@localhost:27017/bearsdev');
```

None of these ways are working for me.

Answer (score 3):

I hope following code may be work.

```
database = {
   host: 'localhost',
   db: 'bears',
   port: '27017',
   options: {
       user: "bearsdev",
       pass: "bearsdev123!",
       auth: {
           authdb: 'admin'
       }
   }
}

mongoose.connect(database.host, database.db, database.port, database.options, function (err) {
   if (err) {
       console.log("connection error:", err);
   } else {
       console.log("MongoDB connection successful");
   }
});
```

Comment: It says authentication failed.

    mongo -u bearsdev -p bearsdev123! --authenticationDatabase bears

Works fine though.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem by uninstalling local node module of Mongoose and then installing the latest version. Probably some intermediate version (~3.6.13) had that bug. But latest Mongoose is good to go.